# How to add custom markers to mapbox-gl js?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to add markers in a map using mapbox gl. I checked mapbox gl example but they have set of default icons predefined in there style. I want to add my custom markers and their styling. And I would be able add a click or hover event over the marker too.

Or can we add custom markers like we add in leaflet. just with the code and defining everything in the code.

I am integrating mapbox gl with react js (server side rendering). I am being stuck at showing the markers on the map.

Did anyone try this before? Thanks.

[Mapbox Custom Marker](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/)

I even tried this example but could not work for me.

[With Custom Image Marker](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/)

Comment: when you say "could not work for me", what does that mean- what errors did you encounter. can you show us a jsfiddle? Custom markers work fine in mapbox gl.

Comment: @snkashis I tried above examples but I am not able to see any marker in map. I want to change markers based on zoom level. is it possible?

Comment: If you want to change markers based on zoom level, perhaps you want a Symbol layer in your map instead of Markers? (It *is* possible to do with markers, but it's convoluted - you'd need to write an event handler to respond to changes in zoom level.)

Comment: @SteveBennett2 I have used leaflet before, it is so simple you can do everything in zoom event, you can even add a marker. It is not dependent on any of the layer. You do not need to go to Mapbox Studio to add a marker.

Comment: what error are you encountering?

Comment: @the_darkside I do not get any error. I don't see any markers at all.

Comment: Did you tried https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl ?